# What is the area of the hexagon of a hexagram inscribed in a regular hexagon?

Tags: geometry

I'm not sure how to solve this, I found this in a math puzzle book with no answers! What is the fraction of the total area of the shaded part?

[image]

Comment: You're going to have to show us the shaded part...

Comment: I tried to add an image, is it showing up? Imgur is blocked here so I can upload but not see it.

Comment: Yes, it is now, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Basic approach.** Divide the shaded hexagon into six triangles in the obvious way.  The rest of the hexagram also consists of six equally large triangles.  Finally, the rest of the outer hexagon consists of six obtuse triangles, each of which is equal in area to the other equilateral triangles (cut the obtuse triangles in half to see this).

This should give you the ratio of the areas as a ratio of triangle counts.

Answer (score 0):

Would you believe me if I told you there if a regular hexagon has side = $1$ and Area = $A$, then if a regular hexagon has side = $s$ it will have Area = $s^2 * A$?

This has nothing to do with hexagons, per se, but is true of all 2 dimensional objects.  Increase the dimensions of a square, trangle, circle or blob by factor of $s$ then you increase the area by a factor of $s^2$.

Would you believe that?

If not, tell me so and I will explain why.  Other wise.

Lets say the shaded small hexagon has side = $1$. The small triangles have sides = $s$.  So the small triangles have height = $\sqrt{2^2 - ((1/2))^2}= \sqrt{3}/2$.

Look at the picture .  The height of the shaded hexagon is the height of two triangles so the height of the shaded hexagon is $\sqrt{3}$. Notice the side of the big hexagon is the height of the shaded hexagon.  So the side of the big hexagon is $\sqrt{3}$.  So $Area_big = \sqrt{3}^2 Area_shaded = 3 Area_shaded$.

So Area of the shaded is $1/3$ the area of the big hexagon.

Method 2:  Notice the hexagon has: 1 small hexagon; 6 equilateral triangles; 6 30-30-120 obtuse triangles.  Cut the obtuse triangles into 2 30-60-90 triangles.  Cut the equilateral triangles into 2 30-60-90 triangles.  You now have 24 30-60-90 triangles and one shaded hexagon.

Cut the shaded hexagon into six equilateral triangles and cut those into 12 30-600-90 triangles.  So you now have 36 small triangles.  12 are shaded; 24 are not.

So 1/3 are shaded and the area is 1/3.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for a more mechanical approach (ad nauseum):

1) In your head, for the shaded hexagon imagine six unitary equilateral triangles orbiting around a central point. For each triangle, height = √(1² - 0.5²) or √(3/4) or √3/2 so area for each = 1/2 * √3/2 = √3/4 then hexagonal area = 3 * √3/2. Notice that if side is multiplied by a factor s then hexagonal area becomes 3 * s² * √3/2.

2) In your mind's eye notice that a line can be drawn from the center of the shaded hexagon through one of these imagined equilateral triangles through one of the six (presumed) equilateral triangles orbiting the shaded hexagon to one of the vertices of the outer hexagon. This would correspond to the side length of another six imaginary equilateral triangles for the outer hexagon orbiting around the same center of the six in the shaded hexagon. That length would be 2 * √3/2 or just √3.

3) area of inner hexagon / area of outer hexagon  would be

(3 * 1² * √3/2) / (3 * (√3)² * √3/2) or 3/9 or 1/3

aside: in Marcus du Sautoy's 'Story of Maths' a millennia-old cuneiform tablet with an equilateral hexagon inscribed in a circle was displayed as their rationale for 360 degrees in a circle. The Babylonians assigned their magic number 60 to each of the vertices, used one side of the equilateral triangles as a radius and outlined the hexagon with a circle, counted up the interior angles and wound up with 360 degrees (which we've been stuck with). Out of curiosity, did a google search on the idiosyncrasies of hexagons and wound up here.